# How to make regex return the value matched in a string instead of a boolean value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

In what i'm trying to do I know which word I want to check the string up against.

What i don't know is if my string is written with "@ $ € т" characters.

So, i know how test a string and check if the word matches.

```
let str = '@la$ka';

console.log(/[@a]la[$s]k[@a]/g.test(str));
//true
```

But is there any method to return the word '@la$ka' in a string instead of a boolean value.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You're after [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) or [`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Comment: It seems so, thank you! Here's a thumbs up as i can't give it to a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `exec` or String method `match`

[exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```js
let str = '@la$ka';

console.log(/[@a]la[$s]k[@a]/g.exec(str)[0]);
```

[match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
let str = '@la$ka';

console.log(str.match(/[@a]la[$s]k[@a]/g)[0]);
```

Comment: @neophoriac either method you need to check if the result is an array, because if nothing matches, they will return `null`.